# android - gradle could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to run my application but I got some errors.
While I've fixed jcenter() with

```
maven {
        url "https://jcenter.bintray.com"
    }
```

I have now this:

Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

running gradle --stacktrace androidDependencies:

```
* What went wrong A problem occurred evaluating project ':app' > Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
```

these are dependencies in general gradle:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
```

and these are ones in my app gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}
```

Comment: Are you having any `.jar` file included in project?

Comment: yes I have 'android-support-v4.jar' , I've edited my app dependencies

Comment: have you put that file in project/app/libs folder? I'm also importing one external api in my project, putting the file in libs and syncing the project worked for me.

Comment: yes '/app/libs/android-support-v4.jar'

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved the problem; it concerned Gradle version compatibility beetween environment and IDE plugin, in my case Android Studio.

This table was absolutely useful: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility

so, since my plugin was 1.0.0 I upgrade my 1.4 Gradle version to 2.3 as mentioned in the table and all went right